# How to unlink the temporary files from /tmp folder in linux using php code

Tags: php, linux

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($tempFilesPath) as $fileData)
{
    $fileName           = $fileData->getFileName();
    $fullFilePath       = $tempFilesPath.$fileName;
    @chmod( $fullFilePath,777);
    if (stristr($fileName, ".csv") !== false )
    {
        unlink($fullFilePath);
    }
}
```

Permission denied error when try to unlink the file from `/tmp` folder

Comment: unlink(/tmp/test.pdf): Operation not permitted in script line number 34 error

Comment: Don't use `@chmod` – if there is an error message, there is a reason for that. Use `display_errors=off` in `php.ini` (or via `ini_set`) to avoid error messages shown on the web page.

Comment: no same error I am getting

Comment: You are normally not allowed to wipe out the complete `/tmp` folder, unless the system is terribly misconfigured. Did you create the offending file in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do is not delete the files in `/tmp`. The system will clear files in `/tmp` by default every time the system is rebooted. This is the default but can be re-configured to delete more frequently. Or place the temporary files in a another directory.